# create graph from text file of vertices and edges

Tags: graph

I have a text file (adjacency list) of a graph represented by vertices and edges. Is there a tool to create a visualization of the graph which can read a text file ?

The format of the text file is

```
0 1 2
1 3 6
2 3 7
3 4 
4 5
5 6 7
6 8
7 8
```

It is an undirected graph. 0 1 2 means 0 neighbors 1, 0 neighbors 2, and vice versa since it is undirected.

Thanks

Rupert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I good graph visualization tool is [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Graphviz uses the [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) format. You can write you graph like this:

```
strict graph {
    0 -- 1;
    0 -- 2;
    1 -- 3;
    1 -- 6;
    2 -- 3;
    2 -- 7;
    3 -- 4;
    4 -- 5;
    5 -- 6;
    5 -- 7;
    6 -- 8;
    7 -- 8;
}
```

To generate a image of the graph, execute

```
dot -Tpng g.dot > g.png
```

Produces this image:

[image]

You can configure `dot` to use a different layout.

If your graph is huge and a manual conversion to dot format is infeasible, you can use the following  python script (it uses [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) with pygraphviz) that read your adj format and generates file in dot format:

```
import networkx as nx
import os
import sys

inf = sys.argv[1]
out = os.path.splitext(inf)[0] + '.dot'

g = nx.Graph()

for line in open(inf).readlines():
    adj = list(map(int, line.split()))
    u = adj[0]
    for v in adj[1:]:
        g.add_edge(u, v)

nx.write_dot(g, out)
```

to exec this scrip execute

```
python script.py graph.txt
```

a file named `graph.dot` will be generated.